# Convert BSTR to char*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char, bstr

Anyone know how to convert BSTR to char* ?

Update: I tried to do this, but don't know if it is right or wrong.

```
char *p= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(URL->bstrVal);
strcpy(testDest,p );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is okay. [`ConvertBSTRToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6%28VS.80%29.aspx) does just that. As for the `strcpy`, `testDest` needs to be large enough to hold the string pointed to by `p`. Note that since ConvertBSTRToString allocates a new string you will need to free it somewhere down the line. Once you are done make sure you do:

```
delete[] p;
```

A couple of caveats though (as you can see from [`BSTR` documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx)):

> - On Microsoft Windows, consists of a string of Unicode characters (wide or
>     double-byte characters).
> - May contain multiple embedded null characters.

So, your `strcpy` *may not* always work as expected.